# Probability that product of distances is less than 1

Tags: probability, geometry

Here is a probability problem I modified. Essentially, you start out with a circle of radius $1$, and throw a dart (we assume that you're a horrible player or that you're blindfolded so that we can neglect rotational symmetry etc...). If the dart is out of the circle, you lose. If it is in, the radius is divided by a factor numerically equal to the distance between bullseye and the point the dart landed in.

Consider the first throw. The initial radius is $r_0 = 1$, and the dart lands on a point with coordinates $(x_0, y_0)$, where the origin is centered at bullseye. Then, the next radius will be:
$$r_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}}$$.

We then throw the second dart, which lands at a point $(x_1,y_1)$. Then, for this second dart to be inside the circle, we must have that:
$$\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}<r_1 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}} \implies (x_0^2+y_0^2)(x_1^2+y_1^2)<1.$$
So the probability that the second dart is in is equal to the probability that $(x_0^2+y_0^2)(x_1^2+y_1^2)<1$ for 4 numbers $x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1 \in [0,1]$. My question is, what is this probability?

My thoughts are that it should be equal to the probability that the product of two numbers from 0 to 2 is less than 1. Is this correct?

EDIT: I think what we can do is:
$$r_0^2r_1^2<1 \implies r_0 < \frac{1}{r_1}.$$
I can then plot $r_0 = \frac{1}{r_1}$ as shown below. If we divide the shaded area by the area of the square, shouldn't we get the probability we require? [Desmos plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75EMN.png) I found the shaded area to be $2\ln2+1$, so that the probability is $\frac{2\ln2+1}{4}$.

Comment: You want $r_1 > r_0$?  (If so, it's okay, but it sounds weird based on your previous comments)

Comment: The radius should decrease every trial. So, $r_1<r_0=1$. EDIT: it should increase.

Comment: Then you have an error in your definition of $r_1$ because it will always be greater than $1$

Comment: Ah damn sorry... slightly sleep deprived. Yeah, it should increase.

Comment: But it still says "the radius is reduced"?

Comment: should be divided, not reduced. Silly me.

Comment: Are you sure this is really the setting you want? The player gets penalized worse if the first shot is close to the bullseye ... Also, with the 2nd shot still the same distribution $x_1, y_1 \in [0,1]$, then for small enough $r_0 < 1/\sqrt 2$ (decent first shot), the new "landing area" for 2nd shot can easily cover the entire unit square, making the success probability one. Is that what you want? (ha, my guess is that you saw the 3Blue1Brown video and wanted to try some variants yourself, but didn't think this through)

Comment: Also, the initial dart board is "radius $1$", the unit circle, therefore the first shot $x_0, y_0 \in [0,1]$ in the unit square will be basically be "aiming at"only one quarter of the board. I think you might have wanted an initial board that is enclosed within the unit square, namely, centered at $(1/2, 1/2)$ with radius $1/2$? Alternatively, the more natural way is to have $x_0, y_0 \in [\color{red}{\mathbf{-1}},1]$ to cover the unit circle.

Comment: ahahah yeah i saw 3B1Bs video, but it seems like my variations doesn't quite work. Oh well...